# Using FirebaseListAdapter only sorting values till 999

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

SOLVED!!

I'm using FirebaseListAdapter and using orderByChild("rank") where rank can be any integer between 0 - 10000. The List is working fine till the rank is 999 after that it doesn't sort items with rank above 999, it simply add them on top of the list.
(In the screenshot on the right side is the rank)

Here's my code:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PlayerList").orderByChild("rank");
    FirebaseListOptions<Usertag> retrieveMax = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Usertag>()
            .setLayout(R.layout.user_tag_model_fullscreen)
            .setQuery(query, Usertag.class)
            .build();
```

This is the Adapter Class:

```
public class FbAdapterFullScreen extends FirebaseListAdapter<Usertag> {

Context c;

public FbAdapterFullScreen(Context c, @NonNull FirebaseListOptions<Usertag> retrieveMax) {
    super(retrieveMax);
    this.c =c;
}



@Override
protected void populateView(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Usertag model, int position) {

    TextView TagTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userTagtvfs);
    TextView TroopsTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userTroopstvfs);
    TextView SpellTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userSpelltvfs);
    TextView RankTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userRanktvfs);
    TextView StatusTxt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userStatustvfs);
    Button RankUP = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.rankupBtnfs);
    CardView cardforitems = view.findViewById(R.id.cardforitemsfs);

    TagTxt.setText(model.getPlayerTag());
    TroopsTxt.setText(model.getTroops());
    SpellTxt.setText(model.getSpell());
    RankTxt.setText(model.getRank());
    StatusTxt.setText(model.getStatus());

    String[] favorites = MyUserTag.getFavoriteListt(c);
    //Toast.makeText(c, ""+Arrays.toString(favorites), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (model.getCocPlayerTag()!=null) {
        if (Arrays.toString(favorites).contains(model.getPlayerTag())) {
            TagTxt.setTextColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
            cardforitems.setCardBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.dullgreen));
        } else {
            TagTxt.setTextColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.darkblue));
            cardforitems.setCardBackgroundColor(c.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_white));
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've searched thoroughly but couldn't find anything about it. Please help! Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Thank you Amitabh Das. 
I changed String Rank to Long Rank in my model class and it's working perfectly.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what's happening please?

Comment: Could it be that because you are using String as Rank and it is sorting as alphabets? Please do correct me.

Comment: @AmitabhDas If that's the case could you please help me how to use Rank as an integer? (Screenshot added)

Comment: @AmitabhDas I think you're right, I should take the value of Rank as Long  not String, but how to resolve RankTxt.setText(model.getRank) after changing Rank from integer to Long?? I'm confused please correct me should I take Rank as integer or Long in my model class??

Comment: @Genie whether you take integer or long practically depends on the range of values you are trying to use, LONG will go a very very long way ;)